# Flutter js unit test

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-js

I have a flutter test project which depends on futter js (javascript environment) [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_js), I wrote a unit test to it. But I keep getting error on this line

> jsRuntime = getJavascriptRuntime();

```
Invalid argument(s): Failed to load dynamic library 'quickjs_c_bridge.dll': error code 126
dart:ffi                                                 new DynamicLibrary.open
package:flutter_js/quickjs/ffi.dart 118:26               _qjsLib
package:flutter_js/quickjs/ffi.dart                      _qjsLib
package:flutter_js/quickjs/ffi.dart 163:19               _jsNewRuntime
package:flutter_js/quickjs/ffi.dart                      _jsNewRuntime
package:flutter_js/quickjs/ffi.dart 206:14               jsNewRuntime
package:flutter_js/quickjs/quickjs_runtime2.dart 51:16   QuickJsRuntime2._ensureEngine
package:flutter_js/quickjs/quickjs_runtime2.dart 165:5   QuickJsRuntime2.evaluate
package:flutter_js/quickjs/quickjs_runtime2.dart 230:9   QuickJsRuntime2.initChannelFunctions
package:flutter_js/javascript_runtime.dart 63:5          JavascriptRuntime.init
package:flutter_js/quickjs/quickjs_runtime2.dart 46:10   new QuickJsRuntime2
package:flutter_js/flutter_js.dart 40:15    

         getJavascriptRuntime
```

can't figure out how to do flutter js unit test. I want some tips and if possible
Here is the reference but it is written only for windows and linux but I need it for android apk.If possible with eg:
https://github.com/abner/flutter_js

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `build` directory, copy file `runner/Release/quickjs_c_bridge.dll` to `runner/Debug` directory.